# Custom packet to send over a socket

Tags: c++, winapi

Any recommendations on how to encode data to send over a socket?

Example

```cpp
struct {
    int id,
    std::string name,
    std::string address
}
```

I have this currently:

```cpp
std::string s;
client_type client = { INVALID_SOCKET, -1, "" };
send(client.socket, s.c_str(), strlen(s.c_str()), 0);
```

I can send a string. What would be the best way to send the above information to the server?

Comment: Transform your data into something machine readable. On of the better text base formats is JSON.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57440928/c-socket-packet-format

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Obviously, they are both by me, worded differently and got different answers. If not I would not have gotten an answer.

Comment: @Bradmage Well, learn how to distinguish socket configuration and actions from payload sent over it. That's the essence. I am not well versed with PHP, but it seems that there are some levels abstracted there.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can you elaborate on your comment? I didn't mention PHP in this question, or socket config. I am literally asking how to properly send a payload of data. send() requires a string so we need to encode and decode that data if it is more than a basic string.

Comment: @ArneFischer Your comment should almost be an answer. JSON is where I would go if I don't get an answer, I kind of thought C++ would have a mechanism for encoding data to send over a socket. It's not like sending data over a network is a rare event..

Comment: @Bradmage I don't think there is out of the box serialization in c++, but there is a ton of free libraries available, I can't speak to available json serializier since we wrote our own (json is pretty simple). If you need some really efficient serialization you can also have a look at protocol buffer: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial

Comment: @ArneFischer Thanks for a decent answer, there are way too many hates on SO and C++. That is what I figured, In this project I'm trying to use as much native as possible for learning purposes. It's been a long time since I coded anything but web apps.

Answer (score 1):

Use a serialization library and convert your data into one of the known data formats via that library. I, for instance, use [cereal](https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal) (check the link for an example) library to serialize my data into json format. [This](https://github.com/fffaraz/awesome-cpp#serialization) is a good list of C++ serialization libraries. Choose the format which suits best for you and then choose a library to serialize and de-serialize the data.

Here is an example of xml serialization with `cereal` for your case (**edit:** compiles now):

```
#include <cereal/archives/xml.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>


struct SomeData{
    int id;
    std::string name;
    std::string address;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize( Archive & ar )
    {
        ar( id, name, address );
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    // this block is used to make sure the destrcutor of archive is called
    // which flushes the output into string stream.
    {
        cereal::XMLOutputArchive archive( ss );

        SomeData myData{4, "name", "address"};
        archive( myData );
    }
    std::string s = ss.str();

    // test output 
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    // send data
    send(client.socket, s.c_str(), s.length(), 0);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cereal>
    <value0>
        <value0>4</value0>
        <value1>name</value1>
        <value2>address</value2>
    </value0>
</cereal>
```

Comment: omg, someone actually answered, with what I was asking, and got a down vote with no explanation! If I don't get a final answer your getting the accepted answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No you miss understand, this answer got a down vote almost straight away. As for my question, it is pretty straight forward, how do I encode an array of data to send over a socket. It can't get much simpler than that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ as Bradmage stated I don't see a reason to downvote this answer without any explanation. If there really is a reason, I would fix my fault whatever it is.

Comment: @bra: This *is* a pretty questionable answer. XML is probably the worst you can opt for, if you plan to efficiently transport, and re-assemble the serialized stream into structured objects. [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) is probably a way more complete and useful library.

Comment: @IInspectable I''ve picked xml just for an example, it only requires two lines to change it into json serializer.

Comment: JSON is equally inadequate. There's just nothing that beats a binary serializer (like protobuf) in terms of efficiency and error discovery. Deserializing XML or JSON always runs a pretty complex state machine, that reads, tries to decode, checks for exactly enough, too little, or too much data, and branches from there.

Comment: @IInspectable I agree with you. I haven't read your first comment carefully. However, I prefer human-readable formats if efficiency is no big deal.

Comment: This is for a network protocol. There is no human reader involved. This is in contrast to, say, configuration files, that are (in part) meant for human consumption.

Comment: @IInspectable I partially agree on you. Human readers may be involved. I know too many cases checking Wireshark to see what is flowing in the network. However, the question is not asking for selecting the best serialization format, neither I suggest the OP to use JSON or XML. You should read my answer carefully, I suggest the OP to select the format which suits best for his/her needs. The list I've shared already contains protobuf, anyway. Also, `cereal` itself can serialize into binary format. And yes probably protobuf is the best for many cases. Thus, I don't see a reason to keep arguing.

Comment: If you need to dissect binary protobuf packets in Wireshark, there are *loads* of [3rd-party tools](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/docs/third_party.md) available. Regardless, this Q&A was closed as being primarily opinion-based, and both this answer as well as the comments following it seem to confirm this.